# Why doesn't my freopen function work?

Tags: gcc, stdout, freopen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXN 15
char forbid[MAXN][MAXN];
int dp[2][1<<MAXN],c[1<<MAXN],*dp1,*dp2;
int cnt_one(int x)
{
    int s=0;
    while(x)
    {
        s++;
        x&=x-1;
    }
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    int t,n,s,a,b,i,j,k;
/*This is my use of freopen function*
************************************/
    freopen("datain.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("dataout.txt","w",stdout);
/*This is just a dynamic program to solve a mathematical problem*
****************************************************************/
    for(i=0;i<(1<<MAXN);i++) c[i]=cnt_one(i);
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        memset(forbid,0,sizeof(forbid));
        memset(dp[0],0,sizeof(int)*(1<<MAXN));
        dp[0][0]=1;
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&s);
        while(s--)
        {
            scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
            forbid[a][b]=1;
        }
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(i%2)
            {
                dp1=dp[0];
                dp2=dp[1];
            }
            else
            {
                dp1=dp[1];
                dp2=dp[0];
            }
            memset(dp2,0,sizeof(int)*(1<<MAXN));
            for(j=0;j<(1<<n);j++)
            {
                if(c[j]!=i-1) continue;
                for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                {
                    if(!(j>>k&1)&&!forbid[i][n-k]) dp2[j^(1<<k)]+=dp1[j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",dp2[(1<<n)-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my program.I used a dynamic program method to solve a mathematical problem.
But when I used the "freopen" function to redirect the "stdout" stream to the file of "dataout.txt",it failed and the file had no data in it.
Could you tell me why I can get the data from "datain.txt" but I can't output data into "dataout.txt"?Is there something wrong with my "freopen" function for "stdout" stream?

Comment: What to the `freopen` calls return? What's the value of `errno` if they fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a segmentation fault that you will not see. If you place a printf and a return after the freopen I think it will work (works for me).

I would recommend you to use "valgrind" on the resulting executable compiled for debug to see at what line the program crashes. If you want someone to help you further, you need to provide an example input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much!I've found the bug in my code which is caused by one of the cases in the input data.But I want to ask that why the output data before the case which crashes can't be written into the output file?The data is written into the file at the end of the program as a whole stream?

Comment: Indeed, the stream is buffered. But this is not the only reason. As soon as you write not initialized memory, you might write over the buffer or over the internal structures that are used to manage the files. You can "wipe out" any possibility of a write...  So, remember, once you write "randomly" to the memory, nothing is guaranteed.